# How to connect only time axis in echarts?

Tags: echarts

We are using [echarts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/index.html) for charting. We have multiple graphs on the page that should be connected on the time axis (meaning if you zoom and scroll on one graph, the other graphs zoom and scroll the same), but *not* on the value axis. We are currently using the `connect` function (https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/api.html#echarts.connect) for this, but this connects both the time and the value axis.

Is it possible to only connect the time axis?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right connecting charts in a group with `connect` method. But you also have to define how your dataZoom works.

It's possible to control both cartesian axes by the dataZoom-inside. For zooming / sliding just x axis (time axis in your case) try these settings for all the connected graphs:

```
dataZoom: [{
  type: 'inside',
  xAxisIndex: 0,
  filterMode: 'weakFilter',
}]
```

In the example `xAxisIndex` stands for the xAxis index of a chart. If you have a few x axes on a same chart instance and you want all of them to be zoomable - just list their indexes in an array:

```
xAxisIndex: [0, 1 ,3]
```

Don't set *yAxisIndex* if you don't want the value axis to be zoomable.

Here you may find more: 
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom-inside.xAxisIndex

Hope this helps.